# Loop through all files in a directory and get average value from each file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I have several files in a directory and I would like to print into a file the average values of the first and last number in the first column from all files. How to do that please?

This code is not complete:

```
# giving names of all files in a directory to the file files.txt - OK
import os
files = os.listdir("/media/linux/DATADISK")

with open('files.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in files:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)

# loading the first column of all files into lists or dataframes with the name/key according files.txt and save average value to file average.txt
for i in files:
    np.loadtext(f'   .  ', unpack=True, usecols=[0]))
    average = (list[0]+list[-1])/2
    print(average, , file=open("average.txt","a"))
```

I don't know how to write the second `for` loop that should load file (1st column), compute the average of the last and first values, and write it to a file. It should do this for all files in directory. I don't know how to write names of files - they have different names and the same extension.

For instance, there are 2 files in directory: klj.txt and gdf.dat

klj.txt

```
4 6 
6 5  
6 1
```

gdf.dat

```
4 5
2 0
8 1
```

The output average.txt should be:

```
5 
6
```

Comment: I editted the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, you don't need the separate loop that writes the files into a *files.txt*. You can do the entire operation as part of the `os.listdir` loop. You just have to form the full path to each file (the path you need to pass to `np.loadtxt` later). Like this:

```py
import os
data_path = os.path.abspath("/media/linux/DATADISK")

for f in os.listdir(data_path):
    f_path = os.path.join(data_path, f)
    print(f_path)

# Output:
# /media/linux/DATADISK/gdf.dat
# /media/linux/DATADISK/klj.txt
```

Then, you can use the `delimiter` parameter of [`np.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) to specify that each row of each file is separated by a space. The `usecols` parameter you put is already correct, if you are only interested in the 1st column.

```py
data = np.loadtxt(f_path, delimiter=' ', usecols=0)
print(data)

# Output:
# /media/linux/DATADISK/gdf.dat
# [4. 2. 8.]
# /media/linux/DATADISK/klj.txt
# [4. 6. 6.]
```

Then you already had the average part of the code correct. But I would recommend opening the *average.txt* file first, so that you won't need to `open` it on every loop.

```py
with open("average.txt", "a") as output:
    for f in os.listdir(data_path):
        ...
        average = (data[0] + data[-1]) / 2
        output.write(str(average) + "\n")
```

Putting it all together:

```py
import numpy as np
import os
data_path = os.path.abspath("/media/linux/DATADISK")

with open("average.txt", "a") as output:
    for f in os.listdir(data_path):
        f_path = os.path.join(data_path, f)
        data = np.loadtxt(f_path, delimiter=' ', usecols=0)
        average = (data[0] + data[-1]) / 2
        output.write(str(average) + "\n")
```

Sample *average.txt*:

```
6.0
5.0
```

The order is going to be dependent on the return of `os.listdir`, so *gdf.bat* would be processed before *klj.txt*.